# How does ctypes know when to throw ArgumentError, but only sometimes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm experimenting with ctypes, and I found something that baffled me. I have a .so file that exports this function:

```
void hello(int a) {
    printf("hello, a=%d", a);
}
```

I call it from Python, but I put a **parameter of the wrong type** to see what will happen:

```
mydll = ctypes.CDLL("libhello.so")
mydll.hello('this is string')
```

This doesn't throw an error, and just prints `hello, a=-1219868708`. But if I pass a double instead – `mydll.hello(1.0)`, then it throws an exception:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

I find it strange because exported C functions usually **don't have information about their signature** (unlike C++ functions), just the name of the function and maybe the total number of bytes of the parameters.

So thinking that maybe ctypes was **counting the number of bytes** to ensure some measure of type safety, I tried passing 2 strings – `mydll.hello('string1', 'string2')`, and there was no error again; it just printed `hello, a=-1223698284`.

So now I'm stumped. What does ctypes check, exactly, so that it knows that a `double` is wrong, but at the same time doesn't know that 2 strings are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ctypes documentation [states](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#calling-functions):

> None, integers, longs, byte strings and unicode strings are the only native Python objects that can directly be used as parameters in these function calls.

To pass another type such as a Python `float`, you have to wrap it in the corresponding ctypes type (`c_double` or `c_float`). Otherwise, you get the `ArgumentError` exception.

So this error wasn't about passing an incorrect type: You'd get the error even if `double` or `float` was the type expected by the C function. As you correctly said, ctypes does not know the actual types expected by the C function and cannot check that the correct type was passed.

Comment: Or set the function pointer's `argtypes` to declare the parameter type instead of manually wrapping it. Note that the default is to cast an integer as a C `int`, so pointer values always need to be either wrapped or typed in `argtypes`.